# Getting an error on incorrect routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I run `node server` I am getting an error and cannot figure out the root cause. I am pasting the error below. I would really appreciate some help as I have spent a lot of time going through stack overflow posts and trying to debug the issue. Thank you.

**ERROR:**

```
C:\Users\desktop\studentSearch\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458
      throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn));
      ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a undefined
    at Function.use (C:\Users\Monica\desktop\studentSearch\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:458:13)
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Monica\desktop\studentSearch\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:220:21)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function.use (C:\Users\Monica\desktop\studentSearch\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:217:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Monica\desktop\studentSearch\server.js:46:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:420:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:535:3
```

**CODE**

```
// ******************************************************************************
// *** Dependencies
// =============================================================
var express = require("express");
var exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var methodOverride = require("method-override");
    jwtExp = require("express-jwt");
    tokenSecret = require("./tokensecret.js");
    cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
// Sets up the Express App
// =============================================================
var app = express();
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

//cookie parser
app.use(cookieParser(tokenSecret));

// Set Handlebars as the default templating engine.
app.engine("handlebars", exphbs({ defaultLayout: "main" }));
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");

// Requiring our models for syncing
var db = require("./models");

// Sets up the Express app to handle data parsing
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.text());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: "application/vnd.api+json" }));

// Override with POST having ?_method=DELETE
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

// Routes =============================================================

require("./routes/html-routes.js")(app);
var apiRoutes = require("./routes/api-routes.js")(app);
var authRoutes = require("./routes/auth-routes.js");

// API MIDDLEWARE
// app.use("/api", jwtExp({ secret: tokenSecret }));
app.use("/api", apiRoutes);


// AUTH MIDDLEWARE
app.use("/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/auth", express.static("./public"));

// USER MIDDLEWARE
app.get("/", jwtExp({
  secret: tokenSecret,
  getToken: function fromCookie(req) {
    if (req.signedCookies) {
      return req.signedCookies.jwtAuthToken;
    }
    return null;
  },
  credentialsRequired: false
}), function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.user) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect("/auth/login");
  }
});

app.use("/", apiRoutes);

app.use(express.static("./public"));



// Syncing our sequelize models and then starting our express app
db.sequelize.sync({}).then(function() {
    app.listen(PORT, function() {
        console.log("App listening on PORT " + PORT);
    });
});
```

Comment: We can't help you if you won't post your code.

Comment: Thanks! I just added it.

Comment: Looks like one of the functions going into `use` is undefined, for example `app.use("/", apiRoutes);`. Is `apiRoutes` here defined?

Comment: Thank you. The issue was actually in the way I defined it because I had (app) after the definition. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was having the (app) in the definition. See below.

```
var apiRoutes = require("./routes/api-routes.js")(app);
```